# Why does my triangle not display after being transformed by glm::lookAt matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I'm trying to display my triangle from different camera viewpoints. To do this, I'm using the `glm::lookAt()` function which creates a 4x4 matrix that you can use to transform your points. This seems to be working fine and as intended when I specify a camera position (arg1) where x, y, and z are all <= 1.0 such as `view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0f, 1.0), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));`.

However, if I specify a camera position such as `view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0f, 2.0), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));` where the camera is a little farther back it doesn't display the shape at all. Why is this the case, in all the [tutorials I am following](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera) the shape still displays?

**My draw code (in a loop) :**

```
 //bind buffers and stuff
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glm::mat4 view;
    view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(2.0, 1.0f, 1.0), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(sp, "view");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view)); 
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

**My vertex shader code:** (Note: in a string and loaded from this string)

```
const char* vertexShaderData =
"#version 450 \n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec3 vp;"
"layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;"
"layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;\n"
"out vec3 Color;"
"out vec2 TexCoords;\n"
"uniform mat4 view;\n"
"void main(){"
"Color=color;"
"TexCoords = texCoord;"
"gl_Position = view * vec4(vp, 1.0);" 
"}";
```

**Points data:** (first 3 floats in each line are the actual verticies)

```
static GLfloat data[] = {

    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,       0.75f, 0.75f, 
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.75f, -0.75f,
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    -0.75f, -0.75f,

    -0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,       -0.75f, 0.75f,
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    -0.75f, -0.75f,
    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,        0.75f, 0.75f,
};
```

I know everything else is working btw, shaders both are working/linked. Normal transformations with roation/translation matrices are working. Without any transformations, the shapes are being drawn correctly.

Comment: where is your projection matrix?? You absolutely need one to transform 3d points to 2d ones. (project on screen)

Comment: @j-p projection matrix? What is that? (sorry, I'm an idiot at this stuff)

Comment: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/projection-matrices-what-you-need-to-know-first